# “I call bullshit” – German counterpart?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom, colloquial, phrase-request

I cannot come up with a good German counter-part to:

> I call bullshit.

Some things I pondered so far include:

- > Das ist Blödsinn.
- > So’n Blödsinn.

My problem is that these directly refer to the thing being discussed, while “I call bullshit” is a bit more generally said (though everyone knows what is meant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More freely translated would be "Niemals" (like "never ever").
But staying close to the *bullshit* I would go for "Quatsch" or simply "auf keinen Fall".

Comment: As far as I think this is the best answer in terms of how harsh it sounds

Comment: *Nie im Leben* as a variant.

Answer (score 4):

> Schmarrn!
>
> Unsinn!
>
> Stuss!

And you can add `Das ist doch …` before these.

Comment: Blödsinn! ;)   ....................

Comment: Schmarrn und Stuss sind eher regional üblich

Answer (score 3):

### bullshit (noun)

- in and around Cologne: *Kappes*
- southern Germany: *Schmarrn* (also written *Schmarren*)
- colloquial: *Mist, Bockmist, Quatsch, Quatsch mit Soße*
- very colloquial and not widely used: *Hirnfurz*
- presentable: *Unsinn, Blödsinn, Nonsens, Humbug* (the latter one originating from English)
- *bullshit* has been adopted by many Germans too, but it is very colloquial.

*Quatsch* and *Blödsinn* (both: *nonsense*) may be intended to be *Unsinn* and to be fun.
However, most people don’t take it that exact.

### to bullshit

Scheiß quatschen, Scheiß(e) erzählen, seichen (Bavarian for heavy raining or urinating)

### to bullshit somebody

jemanden verscheißern, jemanden verarschen, jemanden veralbern

presentable: jemanden in die Irre führen (to mislead sb.)

### I call bullshit

- (Erzähl keinen | So ein | Absoluter | Das ist (doch) ) < bullshit noun >!
- Verarsch mich nicht!
- Verarschen kann ich mich alleine.
- Hör auf, Scheiße zu labern!

Comment: *seichen*? Meinst du *soachen*? Außerdem hast du »Hirnfurz« sicherlich nicht erfunden, es sei denn, du arbeitest bei mir in der Gruppe ;)

Comment: I recommend adding "Schwachsinn".